# I am not able to search for a number within a CSV column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two columns round and day.

Round has a format like this:
,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,

Day has a format like this:
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,

I am trying to do a query for a variable that is in a specific round, day and area.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM variable WHERE round LIKE '%,' + '25' + ',%' AND day LIKE '%,' + '1' + ',%' AND area = 4 ORDER BY position ASC;
```

Although, I am getting nothing back. I have ready many pages on how to do this, but I haven't found a solution.

Is there something wrong with how I am writing it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't store lists of numbers in strings.  SQL has this really great data structure for lists.  It is called a *table*.

Comment: Perhaps use the `||` to concatenate instead of `+`. Although I really don't see a need to do concatenation at all as @mdem7 shows in their answer.

Comment: The string concatenation operator is `||`, not `+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
SELECT * FROM variable WHERE round LIKE '%,25,%' AND day LIKE '%,1,%' AND area = 4 ORDER BY position ASC;
```

Comment: Glad it worked, feel free to mark it as correct answer :)